# Image formed by concave mirror off optical axis

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, spectroscopy

I have seen some examples of using concave mirrors to converge a point source into parallel rays, both of which are off from the optical axis of the mirror, as well as focusing a beam of parallel rays onto a single point which is again not on the optical axis of the mirror.

For example:

[image]

My question is

1. a concave mirror converting a point source into a collimated light rays in a different direction - is this a property of the concave mirror? If so, are there any relations between the incident and reflection angles & position of the point source?
2. In the focusing mirror in the above image, the mirror seems to be focusing collimated light rays onto a single focus in a different direction. Again, how is the direction & location of the focus determined?
3. Are the above properties exact or approximate? Does it change if the mirror is spherical vs parabolic?

In practice, how are the locations & directions determined? By experimental trial and error, or some optical simulation by ray tracing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paraxial approximation, the thin lense equation holds. In this case the points at infinity are conjugate to the focal plane. In particular:

1. The source must be on the focal plane so that the exiting rays are collimated. The position in the focal plane will determine the direction of the exiting rays and are related quantitatively by the thin lense equation.
2. Conversely, your array must be on the focal plane of the second mirror.
3. The previous discussion is in the paraxial approximation so the stigmatism is approximate. Physically, rays diverging point source will be redirected such as there envelope has a cusp at the point determined by the thin lense equation (geometric aberration). The plus side is that it is applicable to any convex mirror. If you want rigorous stigmatism, it’s only possible for the collimating mirror with a parabolic mirrors. However, unlike spherical case, you’ll need to adjust its direction to match the collimated directions.

Hope this helps.